# Use of undeclared identifier - identifier is in "if statement"

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, undeclared-identifier

I have an alert `Use of undeclared identifier 'sql3'`.

If I delete the `if statement`, there 's no problem, but it seems it's not recognized when `sql3` is inside the `if statement`.

Is there a way to fix it?

```
if ([typedepartie  isEqual: @"ami"]) {

  const char *sql3 = 
        [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id 
                                      FROM tabledesquestions 
                                      WHERE pack = ? ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4"] 
                   cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}

listequestionmulti = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

sqlite3_stmt *sql1Statement;
if(sqlite3_prepare(database1, sql3, -1, &sql1Statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
  NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database1));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier `sql3` is defined inside curly braces. Therefore it is purely local to those curly braces. Therefore when you get past that to the next part of your code, it no longer exists.

```
if ([typedepartie  isEqual: @"ami"]) {
   const char *sql3 = // sql3 is born here...;
} // and dies here
```

What you want is more like this:

```
char *sql3 = // default value;
if ([typedepartie  isEqual: @"ami"]) {
    sql3 = // other value;
}
```

Comment: ty matt, so what's the good way to keep sql3 valid after the curly braces ?

Comment: Define it outside (i.e. before) the curly braces.

Comment: What happens in braces, stays in braces! :)))))

Comment: i valid your answer, ty ! . but i would like different string for sql3 depending value of typedepartie. have you a smart way to do that ?

Comment: Define it and give it a default value first. _Now_ do the "typedepartie" test to change the value. Inside the braces can see outside the braces, but outside the braces cannot see inside the braces.

Comment: and after the if statement, what will be the sql3 value ? the first one or these in the curly braces?

Comment: It depends whether `typedepartie isEqual: @"ami"` or not. That is what "if" means!